# python package distributed, get the address of the web UI with easy setup

Tags: dask

I am currently using the python package distributed, does anyone know that how to get the address of the web UI when set up with Python API?

> executor = Executor()

Or I always have to set up with the command line

> dask-scheduler

to get the address of the Web UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the web interface with the following command:

```
>>> executor.cluster.start_diagnostics_server()
INFO -  Bokeh UI at:  http://127.0.0.1:8787/status/
```

This will then print out the address of the web interface.  However it will almost always be at `http://localhost:8787/status/`.

This requires [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) to be installed.